Little-O in exponent
Is  3^{o(n)} = 2^{o(n)}?
In the proof which shows that there is no f(k)n^{o(k)} time algorithm for the CLIQUE problem
by reduction from the 3-Coloring problem,
there was a statement saying that f(k)(3^{n/k})^{o(k)} = 2^{o(k)}.
I wonder how it can be shown.
Is there any formal or informal proof?

"3^{o(n)}" looks like really strange notation. You're sure it's not "o(3^n)"?

Yes. Even the Wiki page which explains ETH uses those kinds of terms.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis

Yes. 2o(n) denotes sub-exponential  time. Consider an easier comparison instead: 2o(n) vs 4o(n):
4o(n) = (22)o(n) = 22o(n) = 2o(2n) = 2o(n).
This is the intuition. I'm sure you can find a more rigorous proof, but you may consider cs.stackexchange.com or one of the math stackexchanges instead as they are better suited for that level of rigour.
